# I am trying to delete some data from firestore but there is a problem (react)

Tags: reactjs, firebase

```
export function DeletePayment(paymentRefs) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("payments")
    .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .collection("payment")
    .where("uid", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .onSnapshot(async (result) => {
      const batch = firebase.firestore().batch();
      paymentRefs.forEach((ref) => {
        batch.delete(ref);
      });
      await batch.commit();
    })
  }
}
```

paymentRefs is an object of arrays now when running this code i get this error

```
Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Expected type 't', but it was: a custom Object object
```

Comment: If you already have the firestore references couldn't you delete them directly instead of performing that query? Perhaps you could clarify exactly what is the type of that parameter in the function.

Comment: `onSnapshot` is to set a listener to a document to have real time updates in your app. Is that what you want to do? Doesn't it make more sense to get the id of the document that you want to delete and delete instead the `onSnapshot` stuff of your example?

Comment: con you show me how to delete them directly ... paymentRefs  is an object that contain an array of different items from the firestore

Comment: @ rustyBucketBay ya you are right but how to delete multiple item at ones now if i send an array of id in paymentRefs how to delete them at ones?

Comment: up to what I know, which is not much, you need to get the documents that you want to delete, and then loop through the ids, calling the deletion for each of the documents like this: `YourCollectionRef.doc(id).delete();`

Comment: @rustyBucketBay Looping and deleting will indeed work, but it will perform several operation to the database. A batch operation is best suited for the task.

Comment: I don't know how that works. Sorry then if that was misleading. With a batch operation you can delete many docs at once?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```js
export function DeletePayments(paymentRefs) {
  const batch = firebase.firestore().batch();
  paymentRefs.forEach((ref) => {
    batch.delete(ref);
  });
  return batch.commit()
}
```

This will delete all document references at the end of the batch and will return a promise that you can handle every time the function is called.

EDIT:
If you have the id of the payment inside the every object in `paymentRefs`, you could try something like this.

```js
export function DeletePayments(paymentRefs) {
  const batch = firebase.firestore().batch();
  paymentRefs.forEach((ref) => {
    batch.delete(firebase.firestore().doc(`payments/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/payment/${ref.id}`));
  });
  return batch.commit()
}
```

Comment: how will firebase know where to look if i don't show him where the is data located and i still got the same error

Comment: That's why I asked you to clarify what type of object is paymentRefs, are these firestore document references of what?

Comment: {0:
creation: t {seconds: 1616611311, nanoseconds: 886000000}
dubt: 200
id: "TbyDxE7zVWYNAev23myX"
patientId: "v2f17n5cf4s8w5xzj7h8"
patientName: "Zeshan Bishop"
payed: 0
uid: "bfQGu9qY6hNCrttFCM56cMwlZmb2"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)} it is a full item from firestore

Comment: Could't this TbyDxE7zVWYNAev23myX id be use to get the document reference?

Comment: it can do i need to get every item from the firestore to delete theme?

Answer (score 0):

Find an example for how to clean some notification collection in case its useful...

```
async function checkForNotifClean(docsToKeep:firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot<firebase.firestore.DocumentData>) {
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const notifCollection = db.collection('notifications')
  const allData = await notifCollection.get();
  allData.docs.forEach(doc => {
    const filtered = docsToKeep.docs.filter(entry => entry.id === doc.id); 
    const needsErase = filtered.length === 0;
    if (needsErase) {
      const id = doc.id; 
      notifCollection.doc(id).delete();
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export function DeletePayment(paymentRefs) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const batch = firebase.firestore().collection("payments").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).collection("payment");
    paymentRefs.forEach(async (ref) => {
      await batch.doc(ref).delete();
    });
    dispatch({
      type: 'ENQUEUE_SNACKBAR', notification: {
        message: 'Payment has been Deleted',
        key: new Date().getTime() + Math.random(),
        options: {
          variant: 'success',
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

that how I did it